# Google Analytics: Tracking code not installed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I was contacted for a problem in the site I have developed. They addressed to me the problem that this site was not getting any reports of page visits and etc.

I went to Google Analytics to check the JS code but it was the same code in the site. But I noticed an error message above, "Tracking code not installed." and "No hits."

I googled for answers and I found one which tells people to remove *www* in the default URL of Property settings. I didn't risk removing it as it may not access the site anymore.

I checked other sites' Google Analytics registered in that email, they were working fine. I need your help to fix this.

Please see the JS code below which I pasted in the header area of the site, Wordpress site by the way.

```
<script>

   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
   ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious: you changed `UA-XXXXXXXX-X` to the urchin for that site, correct?

Comment: No, I changed that here because that part is confidential.

Comment: Have you enabled Universal Analytics for that property?

Comment: How do I enable it? How will I know it's enabled?

Comment: Log into Analytics, the click the Admin link. The Upgrade link is under the Properties group. If you aren't sure, it's not probably not upgraded, which means the code you're using won't work, as noted here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#before-begin

Comment: If you can't upgrade the property, use the old library (which will go away in the near future, so plan on an upgrade): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#quickstart

Comment: There is this "Upgrade to Universal Analytics" message above the property settings. If I upgrade it, will it take effect only to one site?

Comment: I'll try that. I don't have control on this upgrading, I just wait for my client to tell me. Thanks!

Comment: It will affect the property selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script shown is for [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/). If the property has not been upgraded, you need to use the ["legacy" script](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/):

```
<script>   
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();   
</script>
```

You can continue using this version even after you upgrade to Universal Analytics, but this code doesn't report the same data, so you lose a bit of information you could be leveraging.